# How Kustomize finds the deployment's yaml file?

Tags: github, github-actions, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd, kustomize

Following this Github Action auto deploy to GKE workflow:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-google-kubernetes-engine

In the last step notice these lines:

```
./kustomize edit set image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -
```

How does Kustomize knows to which file to change the image?
Does he finds the file by searching and then grab it fully and just apply on it?

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

> How does Kustomize knows to which file to change the image? Does he finds the file by searching and then grab it fully and just apply on it?

Kustomize *doesn't* know in which file to change the image. For the most part, Kustomize doesn't care about "files". In this case, the command is adding a configuration for the [image transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#images-transformer). Running that `kustomize edit`  command...

```
kustomize edit set image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
```

Adds a configuration like this to your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
images:
- name: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG
  newName: gcr.io/my_project/my_image
  newTag: 12345678
```

This means "whenever you find an image reference for `gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG`, replace it with the given values". This will work for deployments, pods, statefulsets, daemonsets, and all other native kubernetes resources that contain image references.

Comment: Thanks. And what are these commands do: `./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -` ? Are they detecting the files who contains the `gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG`, replacing the matched values and apply on them? Should I have my deployment already been deployed on first time on GKE, or it will do it by itself?

Comment: `kustomize build` reads the kubernetes manifests included in your kustomize configuration, applies any transformations you have defined, and then emits a stream of YAML documents on `stdout`. `kubectl apply -f -` reads kubernetes manifests on `stdin` and applies them to your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I don't get it.. "the kubernetes manifests included in your kustomize configuration" which configuration? I have a folder and file called: `k8s/my-depl.yaml`. In the image in this file actually there a Dockerhub image and I want to adopt the procedure described in the guide above. Currently I have no workload on GCP, just the deployment yaml file in my Github repo

Comment: There is a file named `kustomization.yaml` in the directory from which `kustomize build` is running; this is what instructs kustomize which files to process and what transformations to apply.

Comment: Should I have my deployment workload already in my GKE cluster?